# Use 'UNION ALL' in oracle SQL or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all, sqlperformance

I am trying to display employee properties using C# WPF view. I have data in different oracle tables in my DB.

Though there are a set of multiple tables, each set consists of the same structure.  Those tables structure at high-level is...

**Tables Structure**

```
Employee table columns            (EMP table)  : ID, Name, Organisation
Employee properties table columns (EMPPR table): ID, PropertyName, PropertyValues
```

Each employee's ID and Name in EMP table and employee's properties in EMPPR table. Each employee has properties from 40-80 i.e. 40-80 rows per employee in EMPPR table.

Like this each department has one set of tables. i.e. `(DEVEMP,DEVEMPPR)`,
      `(HREMP,HREMPPR)`, 
      `(ADMINEMP, ADMINEMPPR)`,
      `(FINEMP, FINEMPPR)`,
      `(ADMINEMP, ADMINEMPPR)` etc...

I need to fetch employee properties of multiple departments at once where I get lists of employee names department wise.

I am using the following query to fetch employee properties for inputted  names as follows:

```
SELECT Pr.PropertyName, Pr.PropertyValue
FROM DEVEMP Emp
JOIN DEVEMPPR Pr ON Emp.ID = Pr.ID
AND Emp.Name IN (<List of DEV Names Inputted>)
```

Like this, I need to execute for each department.

Is query will be efficient if I use **UNION ALL** with all department tables query and **IN** condition with the combined list as below?

**VIEW using UNION ALL**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW EMPPRVIEW(NAME, PRNAME, PRVALUE) AS

SELECT Emp.Name, Pr.PropertyName, Pr.PropertyValue
FROM DEVEMP Emp
JOIN DEVEMPPR Pr ON Emp.ID = Pr.ID

UNION ALL

SELECT Emp.Name, Pr.PropertyName, Pr.PropertyValue
FROM HREMP Emp
JOIN HREMPPR Pr ON Emp.ID = Pr.ID

UNION ALL

SELECT Emp.Name, Pr.PropertyName, Pr.PropertyValue
FROM ADMINEMP Emp
JOIN ADMINEMPPR Pr ON Emp.ID = Pr.ID

UNION ALL

.
.
.
```

**QUERY FROM VIEW**

```
SELECT NAME, PRNAME, PRVALUE
FROM EMPPRVIEW
WHERE NAME IN (<Combined list of names from each dept>)
```

Approach #2 is easy in implementing as we execute query at once, but I am thinking it degrades query performance.

Which approach is better single query execution with **UNION ALL** or separate query execution for each department?

PS. The inputted emp names list may contain 1000 names for each department and each employee has 40-80 properties.

Comment: the UNION ALL is just one query instead  separated  query are as many as  you do  .. so normally the UNION ALL query is more performant

Comment: The table structure is foobar. Unless you fix it this might be your best option.

Comment: What about using VIEW (question edited)? Even still using VIEW is a good option?

Comment: Well, my impression, both aproaches will be aproximately same **inefficient**. Your only option to get rid of this *NoSQL* table desing (completel **unsuitable for relational databases**) is IMO to take your big `UNION ALL view`, transform it in a *materialized view* add propper indices and make queries on it.

Comment: I agree this should be redesigned and you should suggest that to whoever controls these things. There's no such thing an efficient query, just one that is performant enough for your purposed. Turning it into a view will probably have no effect on query performance.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with MatBailie's opinion; this should have been done as a column in a single Employee table. You could change it to that, and create updatable views mirroring your existing table structure so that the application carries on working while you switch it over to using a single unified table for Employees

In terms of your asking about query efficiency and presumably performance, you're going to have to test it. I only foresee performance problems if oracle won't use an index on each table during the union op..

So to answer your question: it'll work, but you should consider a change the structure rather than persist with finding ways of fudging around what is a problematic initial design decision. The only way to know if it will perform well enough for your requirement is to (stress) test it

Comment: Sorry. I can't change DB design, that is not in my hand. The application context and usage is completely different. Just for explanation purpose, I used the above example.